# MongoDB query with multiple variations in $or query where at least x statements must match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The given data:

```
{_id: 1, group: {value1: true, value2: true, value3: false, value4: true, value5: false, value6: true}}
{_id: 2, group: {value1: true, value2: true, value3: false, value4: true, value5: false, value6: true}}
{_id: 3, group: {value1: false, value2: false, value3: true, value4: false, value5: false, value6: true}}
```

Now we want to query all documents where the following object matches

```
 $or: [
    {value1: true},
    {value2: true},
    {value3: true},
    {value4: true}
  ]
```

**but** with the option that at least e.g. 3 (passed parameter - `minMatchCount`) of the 6 statements have to match. The other way around: 1 statement can fail.

Is there a solution without building a huge `$and` - `$or` query with each possible variation ?

Example output:

```
[
 {_id:1, ...},
 {_id:2, ...}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$expr`, `$sum` and `$cond` to count the matches, and `$gte` to require a minimum:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gte: [
      {$sum: [
          { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$group.value1", true ] }, 1, 0 ] },
          { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$group.value2", true ] }, 1, 0 ] },
          { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$group.value3", true ] }, 1, 0 ] },
          { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$group.value4", true ] }, 1, 0 ] },
          ]},
      3 ] } })
```